# what is the query for MediaStore to get list of newly added image files

Tags: android, mediastore

Can some one help me with sample code for querying MediaStore for newly added image files.

I tried below command and found that the value returned for columns like date_added and date_modify is not correct.

```
_context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, "date_added DESC");
```

when i try to print column values for date_added and date_modified it is like below which is not fully in long value of time in milliseconds. When i tried to convert this string back to date, it is giving me wrong date. Any help regarding the same is appreciated.

```
fileName: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/download2.jpg, 
datetaken 1377587721000, 
date_added: 1377587727 , 
date_modified: 1377587721, 
Id: 10741
```

Comment: Isn't the image with maximum id is most recent? Did you tried that

Comment: Seems to be in seconds since 1/1/1970. So just multiply by 1000.

Comment: but when i copy more than 1 one file all files will have same time stamp and multiply by 1000 will not help to find new file

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks for pointing me to _id, it worked, pls post it as answer and i will accept the same